# Laravel implement policy for user model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I want to create a policy for the `User` model in my application. I have registered my policy using the `Gate` facade in the service provider of my package.

```php
Gate::policy(\MyVendor\Package\Models\User::class, \MyVendor\Package\Policies\UserPolicy::class);
```

In my `UserController` I set up the policy like so (it follows resource controller naming conventions):

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'user');
}
```

The route:

```php
Route::get('{user}/view', 'show')->middleware(['permission:viewAny users'])->name('admin.users.show');
```

And the method to show a user:

```php
public function show(User $user) : View
{
    return view('my-package::admin.users.view', [
        'user' => $user // The user to show
    ]);
}
```

In the policy methods the first `User $user` represents the currently authenticated user. The permission is provided by a role that is configured in the `spatie/laravel-permission` package.

```php
public function view(User $user) : bool
{
    return $user->can('viewAny users');
}
```

How do I pass the user model to be viewed into my policy? For example: I want to check if the currently authenticated user is the user to view and then return true.

I've tried setting the parameter name in my controller:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'userModel');
}
```

And then in my policy:

```php
public function view(User $user, User $userModel) : bool
{
    if($user->id === $userModel->id)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return $user->can('viewAny users');
}
```

But this results in every request being forbidden, they worked prior to the changes.

How do I access the model instance in the policy method?

Answer (score 0):

The route parameter that represents the model to show (or edit etc) must match the name of the parameter declared in `$this->authorizeResource()` method.

```php
Route::get('{userModel}/view', 'show')->middleware(['permission:viewAny users'])->name('admin.users.show');
```

In the constructor of the `UserController`:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'userModel');
}
```

In my policy I now get the authenticated user and the user to view/update.

```
public function view(User $user, User $userModel) : bool
{
    dump($user); // Currently authenticated user
    dump($userModel); // User from the route
}
```